# Div inside bootstrap column doesnt strech in safari on iOS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-safari

What I need is to place 12 divs in a row, with bootstrap.js grid system.
Each column of this row needs to have a border. So, if I put 12 divs with css-class for a column (xs-col-1)
it will break as I put a 1 pixels border to each column.

So my idea was to have an inner div. The problem is that the inner div doesn't stretch. I have tried to put with:100% but this makes not difference. The character inside the inner div goes outside the boundaries for the inner div. The inner div takes up more or less 10% av the width of the parent (xs-col-1).

As I need this on mobile, Im using xs-col-1. And I cannot specify the width in pixels for the inner div.
Is there a way to solve this?

Here is the code for the border put inside the parent. Issue here is that 12 columns will not be on the same row, the column number 12 will go to next row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="border:1px solid black;">
        <div style="width:200%;">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="border:1px solid black;">
        <div style="width:200%;">A</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code for the border put inside the child. Issue here is that the width for the child doesnt stretch. The letter inside the child is much wider than the inner div itself:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div style="width:200%;border:1px solid black;">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div style="width:200%;border:1px solid black;">A</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution seems to be to use "display:table".
When I put this inside the inner div, then it stretched.